No field CREDENTIALS_API of type Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lcdbaba, PID: 2952
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field CREDENTIALS_API of type Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/Auth; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth' appears in /data/app/~~EN1AEGESK24Fnc8XPozi9A==/com.lcdbaba-dgT7WcQW-lcx2E4yCVNJ2Q==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
at com.reactlibrary.devicenumber.DeviceNumberActivity.getPhone(DeviceNumberActivity.java:46)
at com.reactlibrary.devicenumber.DeviceNumberActivity.onCreate(DeviceNumberActivity.java:29)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8913)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)


buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        minSdkVersion = 23

        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'

    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-otp-verify')
    implementation project(':react-native-sms-retriever')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation project(':react-native-razorpay')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
}


